# Create a batch to open new URL in existing Internet Explorer window

Tags: url, batch-file, browser

How can i Create a batch (.bat,vbs,js) that can be run from command line in windows to open new URL in existing Internet Explorer window.

Answer (score 1):

```
start /d "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer (x86)\IEXPLORE.EXE" www.google.com
```

Should do the job.

You'll probably have to adapt the path to fit your version of windows and internet explorer (windows 32/64 bit, ie 32 / 64 bit)

Comment: That doesn't really use an existing open window, does it? I think it just opens a new window.